# Is it possible to configure the Build Configuration to automatically add suffixes for target platform?

Tags: delphi, build-automation, delphi-xe2, platform, file-io

is it possible to setup (ideally from GUI) the `Build Configuration` to automatically add suffixes to the output files according to the target platform ?

I mean, I will have for instance library project named `Project` and I would like to get

```
Project.dll - when I build the project for 32-bit platform
Project64.dll - when I build the project for 64-bit platform
```

Thank you

Comment: So far as I know the only thing you can change is the extension with `{$E}`

Comment: Unfortunately {$E} places the value behind the extension dot, so using `{$E 64.dll}` would build me something like `Project.64.dll` what is not so good :(

Comment: Yes, I realise that it's not what you want. Sorry for not being clear on that point. So far as I know that's the only option you have available. My solution is to use post build scripts to rename the file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I've been thinking about renaming script for post build event, but is it absolutely safe to rename the output files ? I don't know much about PE headers and the things around.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely fine to rename the output file. PE headers has no dependency on the file name.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the info. So, post this as the answer and I will accept it. Anyway, I'm wondering why so important thing isn't supported by the Delphi build configuration.

Comment: To achieve project64.dll you can specify the Library Suffix `64` in Project Options.

Comment: @TOndrej does this only work for packages and libraries, or can it work for apps too?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Funnily enough I was trying to do the exact same thing yesterday for the executable file of my app. I reached the conclusion that it is not possible to change the name of the output file. The only way you can influence the output file's name is with the `{$E}` directive but that just controls the extension of the output which is not what you want.

**Update**

Thanks to @TOndrej for pointing out the [`$LIBSUFFIX`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_directives_for_libraries_or_shared_objects_%28Delphi%29) directive. This does not appear to be modifiable via the IDE project options for libraries, although there is such support for packages. However, it does indeed work when included in the source code of your package. Include this in your library .dpr file.

```
{$IFDEF WIN64}
  {$LIBSUFFIX '64'}
{$ENDIF}
```

This does not have any effect for projects that produce executables (i.e. VCL apps, services etc.) and so I believe the only solution in those cases is a post-build action.

Comment: Thanks to you and TOndrej for the effort.

Comment: Any chance for executable names? Like Project32.exe and Project64.exe

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a build event to rename the executable. In the post build event in project options, you could do something like this:

```
ren $(OUTPUTPATH) $(OUTPUTNAME)$(Platform).exe
```

That would give you something like:

```
ExampleProgramWin64.exe
```

or

```
ExampleProgramWin32.exe
```

It does mean that you can't debug it though, since the IDE doesn't know it's been renamed, so maybe doing a copy is more appropriate.

```
copy $(OUTPUTPATH) $(OUTPUTDIR)\$(OUTPUTNAME)$(Platform).exe
```